# Concatenate dataframes along columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to concatenate two df along columns. Both have the same number of indices.

```
df1
     A   B   C
0    1   2   3
1    4   5   6
2    7   8   9
3    10  11  12



 df2
        D   E   F
   0    13  14  15
   1    16  17  18
   2    19  20  21
   3    22  23  24
```

Expected:

```
     A   B   C   D   E   F
0    1   2   3   13  14  15
1    4   5   6   16  17  18
2    7   8   9   19  20  21
3    10  11  12  22  23  24
```

I have done:

```
df_combined = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```

But, the df_combined have new rows with NaN values in some columns...

I can't find my error. So, what I have to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That returned the expected result for me. If you took out `axis=1`, then you would get NaNs

Comment: Most likely `df1.index !== df2.index`

Comment: @cs95 yes I think so. Can you help me to fix it? I don't know how to get the same index in each df. Thanks!

Comment: @cs95 One of the df gives: Int64Index: 722 entries, 0 to 839 when using .info(). So I think there is a problem there.

Comment: Can't you just reset the index for both of them?

Comment: Seems to work, but it is like it "remembers" the previous index: df.index output still is Int64Index([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,
            ...
            830, 831, 832, 833, 834, 835, 836, 837, 838, 839],
           dtype='int64', length=722)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, merge() works.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

output

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   1   2   3  13  14  15
1   4   5   6  16  17  18
2   7   8   9  19  20  21
3  10  11  12  22  23  24
```

This works only if both dataframe have same indices.